# Equivalent open(file, O_NONBLOCK) in c++

Tags: c++, c, file-io

I would to read a file in NONBLOCk mode, but currently I use the C functions open/read/write/close. So, I'm asking if it's possible to do same thing but in C++.

Comment: What's a problem of using this functions in C++? It's more easy than torment with stdio class.

Comment: @Eddy_Em could one reason be compatibility between platforms? If you want to use `open` on windows well... forget about it).

Comment: @user18490, I never use windows, only Linux.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes there is.

You can include file `<fstream>` or `<istream>` and use `fstream` objects or `istream` objects to open and read files.

For example: `fstream A("HI",ios::in)`

or: `istream A("HI")`

since default is `ios::in` for `istream` objects.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, as `fstream` blocks access to ther processes.

Answer (score 2):

Hi C++ language and std library have no notion of non blocking io so there is non equivalent to open non block, you just use the function as is which an libc api. What you can do is wrap that api in a resource manager C++ class (RAII).